# net-snmp build error: nothing provides net-snmp-client=5.8-r0 even with ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN}-mibs

Tags: embedded-linux, bitbake, net-snmp, mib, yocto-recipe

I'm encountering an error while building net-snmp version 5.8 with the Yocto Project and OpenEmbedded build systems. Specifically, when I add the `--disable-mibs` flag to the `EXTRA_OECONF` variable in my bbappend file, I'm getting the following error message during the build process:

```
 Problem: conflicting requests
- nothing provides net-snmp-client = 5.8-r0 needed by net-snmp-dev-5.8-r0.aarch64
```

RDEPENDS_${PN}-client += "net-snmp-mibs net-snmp-libs" this is the run time dependency for the  client
To address this issue, I have tried using the following configuration in my bbappend file:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN}-client_remove = "net-snmp-mibs"
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN}-mibs = "1"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = "net-snmp-client (= ${EXTENDPKGV})"
```

My understanding is that by removing the net-snmp-mibs dependency and allowing the MIBs to be empty,
it should resolve the issue. However, I'm still encountering the same error.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully
build net-snmp with the `--disable-mibs` flag?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Yocto are you using?

Comment: 'dunfell'  @skandigraun